# kotlin-repl не запускается

Tags: kotlin

Не запускается kotlin REPL.
Помогите починить, пожалуйста. Переустановка  Intelij Idea не помогает.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler
```